# Meteor-Cordova :How To add permissions?

Tags: javascript, cordova, meteor, phonegap-plugins

I created `meteor` mobile application ,and also added

```
 meteor-config.js
```

Added `splash` screens,`icons`,etc.But *How To Add Such Permissions In My Meteor Application* Like `GeoLocation`,`sms`,`Read Contacts`,`take picture` and `videos` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Include the camera plugin details in mobile-config.js as below.

```
App.configurePlugin('cordova-plugin-camera', {
   'CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION': 'To take photos'
});
```

If there are any variables required for plugin, then give those as key-value pairs.

Similarly include for other plugins too.

Refer https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#installing-plugins

http://docs.meteor.com/api/mobile-config.html

Comment: You are adding plugins using meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-camera@1.2.0 similarly using the plugin id "cordova-plugin-camera" in App.configurePlugin as I have specified above. Follow the same for other plugins too.

Answer (score 0):

The answer suggested by @vbharath didn't work for me (Meteor 1.8).
For the camera plugin I've used the solution from [plugin docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/#this-documentation-is-generated-by-a-tool) by using `App.appendConfig` ([details here](https://docs.meteor.com/api/mobile-config.html)):

```
App.appendToConfig(`
<edit-config target="NSCameraUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
    <string>Need camera access to take pictures</string>
</edit-config>

<edit-config target="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
    <string>Need photo library acess to upload images from galery</string>
</edit-config>
`)
```